# nginx evil if alternative?

Tags: nginx, rewrite

Looking to see if there is a better way to redirect a query string other than using if in this situation.

Example URL: http://foo.com/?p=123 to http://foo.com/new

Current using if:

```
location / {
  if ($args ~ p=123) {
  rewrite ^ https://foo.com/new? permanent;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the actual argument value, so that you don't accidentally match things like `op=1234` when you wanted to match `p=123`.

For performance reasons, you should also use `return` instead of `rewrite` unless you actually need regex matching.

For example:

```
if ($arg_p = 123) {
    return 301 https://example.com/new;
}
```

(And of course, `return` is perfectly fine to use with `if`.)